# How to make CSS clip path only reside on top of div?

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

I just wanna ask how we create a clip path that reside only on top of div's. For example, I've a rectangular div like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#rectangle {
  width: 320px;
  height: 600px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-197deg, #E1DFFA 0%, #E1E0FA 34%, #EDFCFE 86%, #EDFCFE 86%);
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle">
  This is the body.
</div>
```

And I have a svg element like this:

```html
<svg width="321px" height="112px" viewBox="0 0 321 112" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <clipPath id="path">
    <path d="M0,54.6239019 C32.8368888,93.6621872 61.3541089,112.45422 85.5516602,111 C151.463201,111.161716 173.963962,18.2383058 321,0 C321.133852,37.3108666 321.133852,74.6442 321,112 L0,112 L0,54.6239019 Z" id="Rectangle" fill="#000000"></path>
  </clipPath>
</svg>
```

If I use css `clip-path` to my `#rectangle` div, then it will clipping (mask) entire div without ignoring the `height`. Like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.rectangle {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-197deg, #E1DFFA 0%, #E1E0FA 34%, #EDFCFE 86%, #EDFCFE 86%);
  width: 320px;
  height: 600px;
  clip-path: url(#path);
}
```

```html
<svg width="321px" height="112px" viewBox="0 0 321 112" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<clipPath id="path">
    <path d="M0,54.6239019 C32.8368888,93.6621872 61.3541089,112.45422 85.5516602,111 C151.463201,111.161716 173.963962,18.2383058 321,0 C321.133852,37.3108666 321.133852,74.6442 321,112 L0,112 L0,54.6239019 Z" id="Rectangle" fill="#000000"></path>
    </clipPath>
</svg>

<div class="rectangle">
  This is the body
</div>
```

So, what I wan to achieve is like this:
[Clip Path Achievement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JZrs.jpg)

Can you guys help what must do to make it clear? Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't find another solution, it might work.

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background:tomato;
}

.container {
  width: 320px;
  height: 600px;
  position:relative;
}

.rectangle {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-197deg, #E1DFFA 0%, #E1E0FA 34%, #EDFCFE 86%, #EDFCFE 86%);
  width: 320px;
  height: 600px;
  clip-path: url(#path);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:2;
}

.linear {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-197deg, #E1DFFA 0%, #E1E0FA 34%, #EDFCFE 86%, #EDFCFE 86%);
  width: 320px;
  height: 488px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  z-index:-2;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="321px" height="112px" viewBox="0 0 321 112" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<clipPath id="path">
    <path d="M0,54.6239019 C32.8368888,93.6621872 61.3541089,112.45422 85.5516602,111 C151.463201,111.161716 173.963962,18.2383058 321,0 C321.133852,37.3108666 321.133852,74.6442 321,112 L0,112 L0,54.6239019 Z" id="Rectangle" fill="#000000"></path>
    </clipPath>
</svg>
<div class="container">
<div class="rectangle">
</div>
<div class="linear">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is interesting, but if the `.white` class must been take off in terms of transparent background, how can I reach that?

Anyway, I still working on it, but thanks for this great answer

Comment: Whoa man, you save my day.. This is exactly what I need. Thank you very much.. Just to make sure, the `.linear` class has to be defined first right? I just wondering if the height can be dynamic, I mean in percentage.

Anyway, your answer is resolve my issue. Again thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very easy solution.  The bottom points in your clip path have a Y coordinate of around 112.  All you need to do is extend the clip path much further down.  For example, in the following test, I have made those Y coordinates 10000.  The clip path should now be able to handle any size div (up to 10000 pixels high).

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.rectangle {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-197deg, #E1DFFA 0%, #E1E0FA 34%, #EDFCFE 86%, #EDFCFE 86%);
  width: 320px;
  height: 600px;
  clip-path: url(#path);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
<clipPath id="path">
    <path d="M 0,54.6239019
             C 32.8368888,93.6621872 61.3541089,112.45422 85.5516602,111
             C 151.463201,111.161716 173.963962,18.2383058 321,0
             L 321, 10000
             L 0, 10000
             Z" id="Rectangle" fill="#000000"></path>
    </clipPath>
</svg>

<div class="rectangle">
  This is the body
</div>
```